# Why is my caching factory method unable to reuse cached objects between Dask Tasks on same Worker?

Tags: multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, dask, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

I'm using Dask distributed to run a processing DAG on a local cluster. As part of that processing, I create DB connection managers to track stuff about processing tasks (poor design choice as it turns out but we're living with it).

Early on I discovered that these managers are not multiprocessing-safe so I implemented a caching factory method for getting a manager object. If the DB manager object already exists for the current PID and the specified connection URL, we don't make a new manager but we reuse the cached one. The idea was to reduce the total number of independent connections to the DB and the thinking was that since a Dask worker gets reused, the same DB manager could be reused by multiple tasks running on that Worker (as long as the connection URL is the same, which it is).

My cache getter looks like this:

```
def get(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname):
    new_db_manager = cls(dbhost, dbuser, dbpass, dbname)
    # This^ doesn't actually create a DBAPI connection. Just stores a configuration.
    try:
        return cls._db_manager_cache[hash(new_db_manager)]  # hashes by PID and connection URL
    except KeyError:
        cls._db_manager_cache[hash(new_db_manager)] = new_db_manager
        logger.info(f"New DB manager initialized {cls}")
        return new_db_manager
```

This has reduced the load on the DB but we are still seeing more connections than expected. The expectation is that n_connections == n_workers but we are seeing n_connections == n_tasks. This indicates that something is causing my factory method to create new managers rather than use the cache ones and I suspect that for some reason the factory cannot find the same cached manager object between Tasks, even when they run on the same Worker.

**Why is my factory method unable to find the cached DB manager object even when running in the same Worker process?**

1. Is this because the PID (as accessed by my factory) changing between Tasks?
2. Is this because the python interpreter gets reset somehow between Tasks?

Comment: By default, dask distributed uses multiprocessing to manage workers and tasks within a single machine. Objects are not shared in memory at all, and are only passed from worker to worker when explicitly required as an input to a function. Things like local dictionary based caches will definitely be recreated in each process. If you want to set up persistent agent properties on your workers you should check out the dask docs on actors: https://distributed.dask.org/en/stable/actors.html

Comment: @MichaelDelgado That makes sense vis a vis processes. However, when a worker process gets reused for running multiple tasks, does the python interpreter get cleared out between tasks somehow?

Comment: I'm not totally sure if a new thread or process is started for each task or if it takes place within the same worker thread/process. however, everything referenced/used by the task as a closure, including global objects, are pickled and passed to the worker as a job spec. so object state, dynamically set class attributes, etc will not (I think) be preserved across tasks. this is different from function arguments, which dask explicitly manages.

Comment: this is different from an actor, which is essentially a long-running task which could process jobs while maintaining state